# How to do JSON Array Multiplication using java? JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json

How to do JSON Array Multiplication using java? JSON Array
I m trying to multiply two JSON Arrays
[1,2] and [1898,0987] Please help me to do that

Comment: Share your code..what have you tried until now

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to convert your JSON Array into data types which you can handle and multiply these.